# Multilevel vertical accordion menu using css

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/uv3qxr68/) vertical accordion menu, but am having some difficulty with toggling all of the

```
.nav li a's
```

siblings children from view.

I.e.

Opening one level should first close all sibling's dropdown menus.

The nav works, but in order to close the 'opened children' is knocking me off a bit.

The Jquery i'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ww = document.body.clientWidth; //used for something else 

        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
        $(".nav li a").click(function () {

            //hide sibling's children first

            $(this).parent("li").toggleClass('hover');
        });
});
```

I would also like advice on the same, however with grandchildren (only one child of the submenu should be open at once).

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

```
+---------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|  <-- (parent) if i open this
+---------------------+
|                     |  
|---------------------|
|                     |
|---------------------|
|                     |
+---------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
+---------------------+
|                     |   <--close these children
|---------------------|
|                     |
|---------------------|
|                     |
+---------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
+---------------------+
```

---

```
+---------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX| <-- (parent)
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
+---------------------+
|ooooooooooooooooooooo| <-- (child) 
|---------------------|
|@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@| <-- (grandchild) when i click on this
|---------------------|
|                     | 
|---------------------|
|@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@| <--+ 
|---------------------|    |
|                     | <--+-- close this section
|---------------------|    |
|                     | <--+
|---------------------|
|@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@|
|---------------------|
|@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@|
+---------------------+
```

**Update**

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/uv3qxr68/1/) - fixed (jsfiddle cursor seems to be messed up at present)

Comment: Are you not reinventing the [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) plugin?

Comment: I didn't think that went as far as grandchildren in terms on open/close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

    $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
    $(".nav li a").click(function () {

        var thisLi = $(this).parent();

        $(this).parent("li").toggleClass('hover');

        $(".nav li").each(function(){
            if(!$(this).is(thisLi) && !$(this).find("li").is(thisLi)){
                $(this).removeClass("hover");
            }
        });

    });

});
```

It first gives your clicked li element the class hover and then removes the class "hover" for every li element which is not the clicked li element or the clicked li element parents.